# Entire function. Prove that $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}, \forall z\in C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ a entire function: $f(R)\subset R.\;$ Prove that $f(\bar{z})=\overline{f(z)}, \forall z\in C$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function $g(z):=\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is also entire.
By assumption, it coincides with $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
By the principle of isolated zeroes, it follows that $f=g$ on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Clean and elegant. +1

Comment: Sorry i don't understand, would you explain more